# JQuery sort and filter list

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, filter, dropdown

I'm running into an issue where I'm unable to filter if I previously selected a sort value. I only want to sort the visible items but when I select a different filter option, the filter doesn't update. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. thank you so much

here's my js:

```
// Filtering plans options 
$('.js-filter-options li a').click(function() {

    // looks for the class of the clicked options
    var allPlans = $(this).attr('class');
    // reset the active class on all the options
    $('.js-filter-options li, .js-input-check').removeClass('active');
    // update the active state on clicked option
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $(this).children().toggleClass('active');

    if(allPlans == 'js-all-plans') {
        // show all the plans
        $('.js-filter-results').find('section.js-filter-results-plans').show(); 
    }
    else {
        // hide plans that don't match class
        $('.js-filter-results').find('section:not(.' + allPlans + ')').hide();
        // show plans that are match class
        $('.js-filter-results').find('section.' + allPlans).show();
    }
});//end

//Dropdown options filtering
$('.js-dropdown-filter').change(function() {
    var $filterList = $('.js-filter-results-plans:visible');

    // Do something for option price lowest to highest
    if ($(this).val() === 'low-high') {
        var lowHigh = $filterList.sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(a).find('.price__amount').text() > $(b).find('.price__amount').text();
        });
        $('.js-filter-results').html(lowHigh);

    }
    // Do something for option price highest to lowest
    else if ($(this).val() === 'high-low') {
        var highLow = $filterList.sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(a).find('.price__amount').text() < $(b).find('.price__amount').text();
        });
        $('.js-filter-results').html(highLow);
    }
    // Do something for option popular
    else {
        var popular = $filterList.sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(a).data("order")-$(b).data("order");
        });
        $('.js-filter-results').html(popular);  
    }
});//end
```

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.jshell.net/tLLfkg5w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am still misunderstanding you, the problem seems to be this line:

```
var $filterList = $('.js-filter-results-plans:visible');
```

When your "1" or "2" filter is applied, `:visible` ensures that `$filterList` starts out containing only two elements, when I believe you want it to contain all four of the elements. So, in the snippet below, I removed `:visible`:

```
var $filterList = $('.js-filter-results-plans');
```

UPDATE: I was going to mention `parseInt`, but you beat me to it. Apart from that, the improper sorting is not caused by the lack of `:visible`, it's caused by the fact that the `return` lines in your numerical sorts are incorrect.  See the modified snippet below. Again, please let me know if the snippet gives the desired behavior.

```js
// Filtering plans options 
$('.js-filter-options li a').click(function() {

    // looks for the class of the clicked options
    var allPlans = $(this).attr('class');
    // reset the active class on all the options
    $('.js-filter-options li, .js-input-check').removeClass('active');
    // update the active state on clicked option
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $(this).children().toggleClass('active');
    
    if(allPlans == 'js-all-plans') {
        // show all the plans
        $('.js-filter-results').find('section.js-filter-results-plans').show(); 
    }
    else {
        // hide plans that don't match class
        $('.js-filter-results').find('section:not(.' + allPlans + ')').hide();
        // show plans that are match class
        $('.js-filter-results').find('section.' + allPlans).show();
    }
});//end

//Dropdown options filtering
$('.js-dropdown-filter').change(function() {
    // var $filterList = $('.js-filter-results-plans:visible');
    var $filterList = $('.js-filter-results-plans'); 

    // Do something for option price lowest to highest
    if ($(this).val() === 'low-high') {
        var lowHigh = $filterList.sort(function (a, b) {
            return parseInt($(a).find('.price__amount').text()) - parseInt($(b).find('.price__amount').text());
        });
        $('.js-filter-results').html(lowHigh);

    }
    // Do something for option price highest to lowest
    else if ($(this).val() === 'high-low') {
        var highLow = $filterList.sort(function (a, b) {
            return parseInt($(b).find('.price__amount').text()) - parseInt($(a).find('.price__amount').text());
        });
        $('.js-filter-results').html(highLow);
    }
    // Do something for option popular
    else {
        var popular = $filterList.sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(a).data("order")-$(b).data("order");
        });
        $('.js-filter-results').html(popular);  
    }
});//end
```

```css
.h-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="js-filter-options">

  <li><a href="#" class="js-1-plan">1</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="js-2-plan">2</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="js-3-plan">3</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="js-4-plan">4</a></li>

</ul><!--/.js-filter-options -->
  
<select class="js-dropdown-filter">

  <option value="popular">Popular</option>

  <option value="high-low">Price Highest to Lowest</option>

  <option value="low-high">Price Lowest to Highest</option>

</select><!--/.js-dropdown-filter -->

<section class="js-filter-results">

  <section class="js-filter-results-plans js-1-plan" data-order="1">

    <div class="price">

        <span class="price__amount">24</span>

    </div><!--/.price -->

  </section><!--/.js-filter-results-plans -->

  <section class="js-filter-results-plans js-1-plan" data-order="2">

    <div class="price">

        <span class="price__amount">34</span>

    </div><!--/.price -->

  </section><!--/.js-filter-results-plans -->
  
    <section class="js-filter-results-plans js-1-plan" data-order="3">

    <div class="price">

        <span class="price__amount">33</span>

    </div><!--/.price -->

  </section><!--/.js-filter-results-plans -->
  
    <section class="js-filter-results-plans js-1-plan" data-order="4">

    <div class="price">

        <span class="price__amount">92</span>

    </div><!--/.price -->

  </section><!--/.js-filter-results-plans -->

  <section class="js-filter-results-plans js-2-plan h-hidden" data-order="1">

    <div class="price">

        <span class="price__amount">44</span>

    </div><!--/.price -->

  </section><!--/.js-filter-results-plans -->

  <section class="js-filter-results-plans js-2-plan h-hidden" data-order="2">

    <div class="price">

        <span class="price__amount">55</span>

    </div><!--/.price -->

  </section><!--/.js-filter-results-plans -->

  <section class="js-filter-results-plans js-3-plan h-hidden" data-order="1">

    <div class="price">

        <span class="price__amount">66</span>

    </div><!--/.price -->

  </section><!--/.js-filter-results-plans -->
  
    <section class="js-filter-results-plans js-3-plan h-hidden" data-order="2">

    <div class="price">

        <span class="price__amount">42</span>

    </div><!--/.price -->

  </section><!--/.js-filter-results-plans -->

    <section class="js-filter-results-plans js-3-plan h-hidden" data-order="3">

    <div class="price">

        <span class="price__amount">109</span>

    </div><!--/.price -->

  </section><!--/.js-filter-results-plans -->
  
    <section class="js-filter-results-plans js-3-plan h-hidden" data-order="3">

    <div class="price">

        <span class="price__amount">57</span>

    </div><!--/.price -->

  </section><!--/.js-filter-results-plans -->

  <section class="js-filter-results-plans js-4-plan h-hidden" data-order="1">

    <div class="price">

        <span class="price__amount">19</span>

    </div><!--/.price -->

  </section><!--/.js-filter-results-plans -->
  
    <section class="js-filter-results-plans js-4-plan h-hidden" data-order="2">

    <div class="price">

        <span class="price__amount">11</span>

    </div><!--/.price -->

  </section><!--/.js-filter-results-plans -->
 
 </section><!--/.js-filter-results -->
```

Comment: Hi MJH, thank you for your answer. I updated my fiddle but the issue that I'm having (you can see it in the fiddle) is that on load the filter and sort options work fine if you don't switch filter number  (1, 2, 3, 4 - in my fiddle i only added content to option 1 and 2). It works if you just leave the sort option as most popular but if you sort by clicking on any of the other two and go to filter number 2, it displays nothing. I'm not sure what's wrong with my script. Can you help me? thank you so much https://fiddle.jshell.net/obnbjf3t/

Comment: thank you for your answer. I had tried that before but the issue with that is that it doesn't just sorts the filtered list but sort the entire list which means that the order isn't correct when sorting. you can see it on this fiddle, I added more options and it doesn't sort correctly. Do you have any other suggestions? I'd like to sort the visible filtered list and when clicking on another filter it shows that specific list with the sorting that has been specified. https://fiddle.jshell.net/9qe0z9mb/ I really appreciate your help

Comment: Please see my re-revised answer.