# jquery price sorting ascending and descending

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am working on website which has functionality for price sorting from low to high and high to low , i have added a jquery for it but it is not working as expected. one of the biggest problem in my code is it is not working in mozilla. 
here is my code which i am using

Popular

Price Highest to Lowest

Price Lowest to Highest

```
<div class="price">

    <span class="price__amount">24</span>

</div><!--/.price -->
```

```
<div class="price">

    <span class="price__amount">34</span>

</div><!--/.price -->
```

```
<div class="price">

    <span class="price__amount">33</span>

</div><!--/.price -->
```

```
<div class="price">

    <span class="price__amount">92</span>

</div><!--/.price -->
```

```
<div class="price">

    <span class="price__amount">44</span>

</div><!--/.price -->
```

```
<div class="price">

    <span class="price__amount">55</span>

</div><!--/.price -->
```

```
<div class="price">

    <span class="price__amount">66</span>

</div><!--/.price -->
```

```
<section class="js-filter-results-plans">

<div class="price">

    <span class="price__amount">42</span>

</div><!--/.price -->
```

```
<section class="js-filter-results-plans">

<div class="price">

    <span class="price__amount">109</span>

</div><!--/.price -->
```

```
<section class="js-filter-results-plans">

<div class="price">

    <span class="price__amount">57</span>

</div><!--/.price -->
```

```
<div class="price">

    <span class="price__amount">19</span>

</div><!--/.price -->
```

```
<section class="js-filter-results-plans">

<div class="price">

    <span class="price__amount">11</span>

</div><!--/.price -->
```

```
// Filtering plans options 
$('.js-filter-options li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // looks for the class of the clicked options
    var allPlans = $(this).attr('class');
    // reset the active class on all the options
    $('.js-filter-options li, .js-input-check').removeClass('active');
    // update the active state on clicked option
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $(this).children().toggleClass('active');

    // hide plans that don't match class
    $('.js-filter-results').find('section:not(.' + allPlans + ')').hide();
    // show plans that match class
    $('.js-filter-results').find('section.' + allPlans).show();
});//end

//dropdown options filtering
$('.js-dropdown-filter').change(function() {

    var $filterList = $('.js-filter-results-plans');

    // show plans for lowest to highest price
    if ($(this).val() == 'low-high') {
        var lowHigh = $filterList.sort(function (a, b) {
            return parseInt($(a).find('.price__amount').text()) > parseInt($(b).find('.price__amount').text());
        });
        $('.js-filter-results').html(lowHigh);
    }// if
    // show plans from highest to lowest price
    else if ($(this).val() == 'high-low') {
        var highLow = $filterList.sort(function (a, b) {
            return parseInt($(a).find('.price__amount').text()) < parseInt($(b).find('.price__amount').text());
        });
        $('.js-filter-results').html(highLow);
    }// else if
    // show most popular plans
    else {
        var popular = $filterList.sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(a).data("order")-$(b).data("order");
        });
        $('.js-filter-results').html(popular);  
    }// else
});//end
```

Comment: Check your firefox version, it may be old.

Comment: If it's not working as expected how you suppose it to work in mozilla? not mozilla's fault.

Comment: may be this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777592/jquery-sort-and-filter-list

Answer (score 0):

I checked this and it works in Firefox

```
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="pricing" value="highLow"> High - Low<br>
  <input type="radio" name="pricing" value="lowHigh" checked> Low - High<br>
</form>
<div class="sorted">
  <div class="price">
    <span class="price__amount">24</span>
  </div>
  <!--/.price -->
  <div class="price">
    <span class="price__amount">34</span>
  </div>
  <!--/.price -->
  <div class="price">
    <span class="price__amount">33</span>
  </div>
  <!--/.price -->
  <div class="price">
    <span class="price__amount">92</span>
  </div>
  <!--/.price -->
  <div class="price">
    <span class="price__amount">44</span>
  </div>
  <!--/.price -->
  <div class="price">
    <span class="price__amount">55</span>
  </div>
  <!--/.price -->
  <div class="price">
    <span class="price__amount">66</span>
  </div>
  <!--/.price -->
  <div class="price">
    <span class="price__amount">42</span>
  </div>
  <!--/.price -->
  <div class="price">
    <span class="price__amount">109</span>
  </div>
  <!--/.price -->
  <div class="price">
    <span class="price__amount">57</span>
  </div>
  <!--/.price -->
  <div class="price">
    <span class="price__amount">19</span>
  </div>
  <!--/.price -->
  <div class="price">
    <span class="price__amount">11</span>
  </div>
  <!--/.price -->
  <hr>
</div>
```

And just a simple JQuery bit

```
var valARR = [];

$(".price__amount").each(function(index) {
  valARR.push($(this).text());
});

function init() {
  for (var i = 0; i < valARR.length; i++) {
    $(".sorted").append(
      '<div class="price"><span class="price__amount">$' +
        valARR[i] +
        ".00</span></div>"
    );
  }
}
$("input")
  .change(function() {
    var _this = $(this);
    valARR.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (_this.val() == "lowHigh") {
        return a - b;
      } else {
        return b - a;
      }
    });

    $(".sorted").html("");
    init();
  })
  .change();
```